# Copy/Paste features as a Tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis, append

I am an generating a proccess with the process simulator from QGIS. My final task is to 'append' the features from one temporary layer created within the proccess to another layer in my proyect. I have seen that some people is using the 'merge layers tool' but I dont want to create a new layer because i have already set up the simbology on my project layer. I just want to copy/paste the features on it as the tool 'append' does it in ArcGIS.

Comment: This is well explained in [the QGIS docs](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html?#cutting-copying-and-pasting-features) via QGIS GUI. However, if your question is more on using that tool in a Processing workflow, have a look at the [AppendFeaturesToLayer](https://github.com/gacarrillor/AppendFeaturesToLayer/) plugin.